# How do I automatically fill a table column?

Tags: qgis

I would like to solve a basic problem. I need to automatically fill a table in QGIS. Is it possible to fill a table according to this: `if column "SPECIES" contains string "DOG" → write to column "CODE" integer 1`?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the Field Calculator. If you open the attribute table and click on the little button at the bottom that looks like a calculator (you may need to enter "editing" mode first). This brings up the calculator which allows you to do this sort of thing.

The manual (http://qgis.org/en/documentation/manuals.html) has information about use of the Field Calculator starting on Page 76